# Show that the set of provable sentences is decidable.

Tags: logic, computability

I am asked to show that if T is a finite L-theory (L finite) then there exists an algorithm that generates the set $\{ \varphi \in Sent(L) : T \vdash \varphi \}$.

From this I understand that I am supposed to show that the set is decidable hence I should show that the characteristic function of the set is recursive. However I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Could you make a TM that writes down all the 1-step-provable-sentences (the axioms of $T$)?

Comment: I don't know the definition of a Turing machine yet. Is there a way to do this problem without Turing machines?

Comment: Could you make an algorithm that writes down all the 1-step-provable-sentences (the axioms of $T$)?

Comment: The set of provable sentences from the empty theory (no axioms) is not decidable, in general, even for finite languages. So there is some mistake in the statement or interpretation of the problem.  Similarly, the set of statements in the language of groups provable from the group axioms is not decidable (due to Tarski).  The set of statements in the language of arithmetic provable from Robinson's arithmetic $Q$ is not decidable (and $Q$ is a finitely axiomatized theory.)

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to prove that the set is decidable, because, as @CarlMummert explained, that's often false. I think "an algorithm that generates the set" is intended to mean an algorithm that lists all the members of the set. So you're supposed to show that the set is computably enumerable.